# Puppy vs Adjustable Bed

Tags: dogs, safety, puppy

Got an adjustable bed. Love it.
Got an adorable beagle puppy. Love him.
Let the two be alone in the room together.
Beagle is still adorable. Bed no longer adjusts.

Looking to buy a new adjustable bed (electrician pronounced the old one dead). Need a way to make it puppy safe.

What I've "tried":

[image]

Have looked at getting an adjustable bed frame (only had adjustable base and mattress before). However, as you can see here, even a high frame with tall sides still leaves enough room for a dogs head to get underneath the base once it's adjusted.

If there is a frame that hides the underside even when adjusted my googling hasn't found it. But rather than insist that a frame is the solution I'd rather simply ask:

How do you puppy proof an adjustable bed?

Comment: Is it possible to not let them be together unsupervised?

Comment: @Allerleirauh oh sure. Get rid of one of them. I keep the yard gate closed but I still chip the dog. Looking for a better solution then keep the door shut.

Comment: Next time it could be the puppy who "no longer works" :( electric wires and teething are a high risk combination...

Comment: If you can not close the door, you can add some sort of fence, you simple step over, but the puppy is too small to do so. I saw this kind of fence at my friends home, when the puppy was too small to take the stairs safely. Because it was an open stair, they built a maybe 30cm high fence around the stair's base